# Access internet through a tunnel

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, tunnel

I have created a VPN tunnel between by system and my server. My server is whitelisted with another server. So while in development phase I want the request originating from my system to go to the other server via my server through the tunnel. How do I manage that. After establishing the VPN connection internet is disabled in my system.

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-O5XF4EL4U7S
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 PM Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-E0-81-B2-41-CA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e970:c3a0:5e22:c5bd%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.73.44.186(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.73.44.187(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.73.44.188(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.73.44.189(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.73.44.190(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::2d0:2ff:fef0:5400%12
                                       76.73.44.185
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 76.73.0.2
                                       76.73.0.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

PPP adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : RAS (Dial In) Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.82.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 8:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.wds.fdcservers.net
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-54-55-4E-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{4BB69970-73AD-4251-AF83-EDF56E687
C94}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4c49:2cba::4c49:2cba(Preferred)
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4c49:2cbb::4c49:2cbb(Preferred)
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4c49:2cbc::4c49:2cbc(Preferred)
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4c49:2cbd::4c49:2cbd(Preferred)
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4c49:2cbe::4c49:2cbe(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 76.73.0.2
                                       76.73.0.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 15:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Can you please explain your topology in more detail? include IP addresses, server names. (Best to post an `ipconfig /all` and a `route print` from all involved systems)

Comment: @MichelZ unable to share the IP details. but the server is just a dedicated server from a hosting company with windows 2k8 server installed on it.

Comment: Then at least post the details and change the ip address to something else... we need to see those details :)

Comment: @MichelZ shared original details

Answer (score 1):

As for your "Internet" problem, do this:

> 1. click the network icon in the notification are of the taskbar,
> 2. click "Connect or disconnnect...",
> 3. right-click the VPN connection,
> 4. click "Properties",
> 5. click the "Networking" tab
> 6. double-click "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)",
> 7. click the "Advanced..." button,
> 8. and there it is: DISABLE "Use default gateway on remote network".
> 9. Click OK three times.

Comment: I did that. Now I am able to browse the internet. But thats not what I want. I want the data to be routed by my VPN server. Something like i want the VPN to act as proxy.